# How does this control loop work?

Tags: power-electronics, control, boost

The following description is taken from maximintegrated website (this [link](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/2/2031.html) specifically), and after reading and trying to analyze the control technique it still does not make sense to me:

**1** - In the figure it shows a boost converter, and it reads:

> This duty cycle change then moves the output voltage to reduce the error signal to **zero**, thus completing the control loop.

From my point of view if that \$V_{ERROR}\$ is supposed to converge to zero for a steady state output voltage, the duty cycle should be kept steady at 0% since \$V_{RAMP}\$ will always be greater than \$V_{ERROR}\$ and the latter seemingly not subject to variations, which cannot be true since it meant the circuit would stop switching. A comparison I have used to understand it better is when I think of a PI controller, which brings the error to zero but has a memory in its output value, so it only responds to small variations once the steady state value is reached.

[image]

My question is: **How is this control loop supposed to keep the output voltage steady regardless of for instance, load variations, if the error being reduced to zero would actually stop the switching?**

By the way in the timing diagram they've inverted \$V_{SWITCH}\$ since it should be high when \$V_{ERROR} > V_{RAMP}\$, but it does not matter to the main question since it must've been a little mistake.

**EDIT:**

Following the main discussion, the figure below shows the circuit I have been inspired from to get this control loop done. It comes from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5R_QCurh_iM&t=432s&ab_channel=GreatScott%21) in which the designer himself references maximintegrated's [website](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/2/2031.html).

[image]

I tried to replicate the idea using an op-amp, a behavioral voltage supply and a pulse source to generate the triangular wave in LTspice, trying to replicate the idea described in maxim's document and here are the results.

[image]

[image]

I have set a value of \$V = 5\,V\$ which is the reference for \$ 50\,V \$ in the output since \$V_{feed} = 0.1\,V_{out}\$.

**Result**: As you can see, my voltage level in the output is \$V_{out} \approx 25\,V\$, which is not what I have set the system for. Also, I tried changing values of the load and the output voltage also changes and that's not what I wanted either.

Finally, I'm probably mistaken in how this controller works and would really like to find out what is wrong.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I suspect that "the error signal" doesn't mean \$V_{ERROR}\$ but instead \$(V_{in-} - V_{REF})\$...Actually, maybe I'm wrong, those should just be the same but with a multiplication by the gain. Maybe they're assuming positive and negative supplies on the opamps but you're thinking single supply? So \$V_{ERROR} = 0\$ is actually in the middle of the ramp, which can go negative?

Comment: @Justin I thought like that so, but it may be very misleading if that's the point, at least in my point of view. I've seen a guy work a circuit with such feedback and it would work.

Comment: The schematic as shown is not inherently stable as the LCR ratios affect Q, the startup power maybe is outrageously greater than the design full load. There is no PFM soft start nor any lead/lag compensation nor any proper gain control. It can be made to regulate, but stability is not to be assumed.

Comment: Based on some of your comments on answers, I think the problem is you are assuming that zero is not the halfway point of the ramp. The ramp *is* centered around 0.0V, going to negative voltage half of the time and positive the other half.

Comment: @Justin Exactly, but I've seen it be made with a ramp going from 0 to a +V being V>0, which I don't see making much sense without compensation.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yes that's something I've been thinking of since I started analyzing it, but the thing is I've seen a guy get this circuit done on internet although I don't know whether it's true or not (he's kind famous so I don't think he'd cheat only to get more viewers).

Comment: @IronMaiden maybe it would help if you gave us a link to the demonstration? Maybe more eyes will clear up whatever needs to be cleared up?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Yes, I'm doing it at this moment indeed! I read your answer and it actually opened my eye into the idea of the controller inside the IC, but the circuit I'm trying to do is very similar to the rough controller idea based on the figure I posted in the main question. I'll update the images very soon

Answer (score 3):

> *How is this control loop supposed to keep the output voltage steady
> regardless of for instance, load variations, if the error being
> reduced to zero would actually stop the switching?*

Basically, and in a nutshell, the error cannot reduce to zero. In a practical controller, the open loop gain may be numerically a thousand to 1 million so, if the output is (say) at 50 % of its range, then the error signal magnitude is a tiny fraction of 1 %. There has to be an error (no matter it being small), that drives the output to very, very close to the demanded level.

Exactly the same story for an op-amp; we say that both inputs are at the same voltage but that isn’t, strictly speaking, the precise truth.

And, in addition, if I address this point: -

> *the error being
> reduced to zero would actually stop the switching?*

No it wouldn't because of the comparator and triangle wave shown below. They ensure that the system remains clocking out at the required duty cycle: -

[image]

---

Regards your simulation, now that I've had a good chance to look at it, you haven't got enough "gain" in the system to drive the error towards an acceptable value: -

[image]

Your error amplifier is only a gain of unity so, try adding a gain of ten stage between the op-amp output (U3) and the purple error box shown above. If things start to look unstable you might need a few pF across R11. If OK, proceed to increase the extra gain factor higher and higher. As you do so, the actual output will move ever closer to the target demand.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119693/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-how-does-this-control-loop-work).

Answer (score 1):

> A comparison I have used to understand it better is when I think of a PI controller, which brings the error to zero but has a memory in its output value, so it only responds to small variations once the steady state value is reached.

That is indeed how the control circuit of a switching converter generally works. The diagram in your question does not accurately show this. However, the next diagram in the tutorial helps a little.

[image]

Pin 8, in that diagram is connected to a resistor, capacitor pair, and these provide the "integral" part of the control.

If we go to the [datasheet for the MAX1932](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1932.pdf) figure 1 page 10, we can see that the "comp" (compensation) pin, is connected to the Verror signal. So this signal is "integrated" (or at least "stabilized") before being fed into the ramp comparator. This is typical of how switching converters work. (There are some chips that do not provide a pin for external control of compensation.)

> My question is: How is this control loop supposed to keep the output voltage steady regardless of for instance, load variations, if the error being reduced to zero would actually stop the switching?

In the absence of compensation, a given error signal will cause a given duty cycle to be generated. If the given error signal is "zero", some particular duty cycle will be generated. That duty cycle will not be zero, nor 100%, but somewhere in the middle. If the error signal goes positive or negative, the duty cycle will become greater or smaller appropriately.

Let's call the duty cycle generated by a zero error signal \$D_0\$.

Let's call the output voltage for which the converter is designed \$V_0\$

If a duty cycle of \$D_0\$ causes the converter to output \$V_0\$, then the error signal generated by the output will also be zero. The converter can possibly be stable at this point.

If a duty cycle of \$D_0\$ causes the converter to output a voltage different from \$V_0\$, then the circuit will not be stable at its designed output voltage. There might be a stable point very near the designed output voltage. Alternatively, the output voltage may oscillate around some point near the designed output voltage. The compensation referred to previously is intended to stabilize the circuit, and prevent such oscillations.

Comment: It's exactly this stable point very near the designed output voltage that my circuit is not being able to converge, and I've assembled the circuit just like it was done in maxim's website. For me it's weird because if there is not an integrator taking part of the control loop, I don't see how the circuit will actually converge, although there's lots of explanations of this mode on the internet.

Comment: Moreover, I have just updated the additional information about the circuit.

Comment: OK. I think I know what is going on. In the video, he demonstrates a falling voltage when (what looks like) a 1/4 watt resistor is added as a load. From this, I conclude that the boost converter is operating in discontinuous conduction mode (DCM). The control mechanism is different in DCM than in CCM, DCM is entered when the load is "light", in relation to the L (and C?) of the converter. In your schematic, you have a 50\$\Omega\$  R1, What happens when the load resistance is increased, to say 1K? What is your output voltage then?

Comment: I have changed R1 to 1k and now the output voltage reaches a steady state value of 40V in 240ms

Comment: So maybe my circuit is not working in DCM like his? That's something I hadn't thought about to be honest. Yet I still don't understand how my circuit could not follow the idea presented by maxim's document.

Comment: I can simulate anytime needed, I've been trying to get this done in LTspice actually, because I don't have any PCB at the moment. My load is the one in LTspice, I have no real circuit. I have just changed to 3.3K and I got 43.35V @ steady state in roughly 580ms.

Comment: That's fine, thank you very much. I'll keep trying some simulations to see what can be improved in the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the following circuit does not output 50V lies with the values of the resistors, the reference voltage and the set points of the triangle wave.

[image]

When the circuit is first started, the \$V_{out}\$ does pass through 50V. At that point, \$V_{fb}\$ is approximately 5V, and \$V_{err}\$ approximately 0V. So, the duty cycle is approximately 0, and so \$V_{out}\$ would fall (if there were no excess energy in the LC components).

When \$V_{out}\$ falls to approximately 25V, \$V_{fb}\$ is approximately 2.5V, and \$V_{err}\$ is approximately 2.5V, and the duty cycle will be about 50%. The output corresponding to 50% when \$V_{in}\$ is 12V, will be 24V. So the output should still fall but not by much.

The equations we have are

\$V_{out}=\frac{V_{in}}{1-D}\$

\$V_{fb}=K_{fb}V_{out}\$

\$V_{err}=V_{ref}-V_{fb}\$

\$D=\frac{V_{err}}{V_{triangle}}\$

There are multiple ways to get a 50V output. The easiest way is to adjust \$K_{fb}\$ so that, working backward, we get 50V. Notice that in the video from which the OP modeled his circuit, Great Scott used a variable resistor. He did not assume that if \$K_{fb}\$ were set to 0.1, that the output would be 10 x \$V_{ref}\$. That is, he did not assume linearity between 1/\$K_{fb}\$ and the output voltage. That is the crux of the matter.

Now, to get a 50V output from a 12V input, we need a duty cycle of 76%. To get a duty cycle of 76%, we need \$V_{err}\$ to be 3.8V. To get \$V_{err}\$ to be 3.8V we need \$V_{fb}\$ to be 1.2V. To get \$V_{fb}\$ to be 1.2V with a 50V \$V_{out}\$ we need \$K_{fb}\$=0.024. To get \$K_{fb}\$=0.024, we can choose R7=40.66k\$\Omega\$ and R8=1k\$\Omega\$.

Note well, that this circuit has poor input regulation. Aside from the huge transient voltages, when the circuit starts up, if \$V_{in}\$ should change, so will \$V_{out}\$. If \$V_{in}\$ should change *significantly*, so will \$V_{out}\$.

Comment: Yes, I think you've spotted what I was in trouble understanding. I changed the values and it did work and yes, I was assuming linearity all this time, maybe because I had a PI fashion mindset. I think things are getting more clear now

Answer (score 0):

The compensation pin is applied to the current output of the error amplifier. There is a series RC circuit to ground in the actual practical circuit.

So you get a proportional term (because of the R) and an integral term (because of the C).

There is your PI controller.

Comment: The PI in the IC part I could actually understand, the problem is I'm trying to replicate the circuit they've made as shown in the picture I originally posted.

Comment: The shown error amplifier has time varying gain that is asymptotic to infinity.

Comment: How do I find that the error is asymptotic to inifinity? I really wish I'd understand how it works